# How To Remove The Black Lines On Layout Screen In Android?

Tags: android-layout

I have frame layout in which I placed an image with `480x800` resolution to fill the screen. Now I am placing a button on to the image.

My XML looks like this....

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
         android:layout_width="480px" 
         android:layout_height="800px"
         android:src="@drawable/img">
 </ImageView>
 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01" 
        android:layout_width="174px" 
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40px"   
        android:layout_marginRight="16px">

   <Button android:id="@+id/callend2"
        android:layout_width="176px"
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:paddingLeft="20px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:textColor="#f5f5f5"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:background="@drawable/csh_call_red_btn_normal"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/call_end_call_icon"
        android:text="call end">
   </Button>  
 </FrameLayout>
```

My problem is I am getting black line on the border of the Button or Inner Frame Layout...

Comment: please consider adding image of the issue which will help understand it

Answer (score -1):

It would help to know what kind of view contains the `ImageView` and `FrameLayout`.

But if you want an image for a background, why not just set the `android:background` attribute of the root view of your hierarchy?

Comment: Hi Dude That Image Will Be Changing Dynamically. Both The views Are In Frame layout Only

Comment: You can change backgrounds dynamically with setBackgroundResource (or setBackgroundDrawable).